# Dificuldade ao criar .JAR no NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

Estou tentando criar um .JAR no NetBeans, mas recebo as mensagens :

> C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\Project\nbproject\build-impl.xml:993: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\Project\nbproject\build-impl.xml:837: copylibs doesn't support the "excludeFromCopy" attribute

O NetBeans não gera o .JAR por causa desses erros.

Minhas especificações

> Versão do OS = Windows 7 64 Bits
>   Versão do Java = 1.7.0_55
>   Versão do Netbeans = 7.0.1

Comment: de acordo com a mensagem de erro tente remover o atributo, `excludeFromCopy` do seu xml.

Comment: a propósito, considere passar a usar o Maven

Comment: Como eu faço isso meu amigo ? Aonde eu encontro o arquivo ?
Muito obrigado.

Comment: Pelo que eu li e entendi nesse [relatório de bugs](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=231468) da própria NetBeans isso é um bug e para consertar basta atualizar para a versão 7.4 ou mais atual.

Comment: Isso mesmo meu amigo, era só atualizar ! Valeu mesmo !

Comment: Como eu não tinha certeza que apenas a atualização ia resolver seu problema eu tinha escrito como contrário, já que resolveu converti para resposta ;)

Comment: só para te explicar, quando existe uma resposta que te resolve o problema marque ela como aceita, assim fica claro que sua duvida foi sanada, para fazer isso basta clicar no tick (um V que fica  do lado da respota) para deixá-lo verde

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acordo com esse [relatório de bugs](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=231468) da própria NetBeans isso é um bug e para consertar basta atualizar para a versão 7.4 ou mais atual.